# Run a thread to close the program when user press a specific key

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to run a separate thread to close the program when user press a specific key. This is the structure of my program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;


DWORD WINAPI foo(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
 //do something
 return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI boo(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
 //do something
 return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    HANDLE foo1,boo1;

    while(true)
    {
        foo1 = CreateThread(NULL,0,foo,NULL,0,NULL);
        boo1= CreateThread(NULL,0,boo,NULL,0,NULL);
        //do something

    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have created two threads inside of always true while loop to keep the program running . So I want to add another thread to get user input whenever user press a key (while program is running) and after comparing it with specific already defined character, if they match close the program.

I have no idea of doing that.Can someone help me?

PS : I have to do that using threads only :)

Comment: Why use threads for something as simple as this? That seems like massive overcomplication.

Comment: Actually I was asked to do that using threads. That's why.

Comment: When you create threads, you should check that the handle returned by  CreateThread call is valid, otherwise you can get a memory access exception. After you are done with threads you should close handles with CloseHandle function.

Comment: Can you please enlighten me? I'm new to threads. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not creating two threads. You are creating threads in an infinite loop until you run out of memory. Besides, your main is already running on a separate thread, so you can do your user input there. For example:

```
HANDLE hevent = NULL;
bool done = false;

DWORD WINAPI foo(LPVOID lpParameter)
{

    while(!done)
    {
        ::WaitForSingleObject(hevent, -1);
        printf("\rfoo");
        Sleep(1000);
        ::ResetEvent(hevent);
    }
    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI boo(LPVOID lpParameter)
{

    while(!done)
    {

        printf("\rboo");
        Sleep(1000);
        SetEvent(hevent);
    }
    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    HANDLE foo1,boo1;

     hevent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, TRUE, NULL);

     foo1 = CreateThread(NULL,0,foo,NULL,0,NULL);
     boo1= CreateThread(NULL,0,boo,NULL,0,NULL);
     HANDLE handles[] = {foo1, boo1};
     char c = getchar();
     done = true;
     ::WaitForMultipleObjects(2, handles, TRUE, -1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I see that you have point what's wrong with my code. But I'm using windown.h header file and when I create the thread it starts to run right? Please correct me if I'm wrong. And please be kind enough to tell me how can I do the exact thing only using two threads without creating infinite threads. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: When you create a thread with the arguments shown above, it gets created and enters the running state (assuming thread creation succeeded). The CreateThread function returns immediately after the thread was created. To create two threads you should modify your main function as shown in the answer above. It creates two threads, then waits for the user input. After the input it waits for threads to exit, then returns. Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Actually I was asked to develop this to display two strings one after another until user decides to exit. ( ex : display foo and boo like flashing. When foo shows boo string should disappear and other way around. ) That's why I needed the infinite while loop. And also this should happen until user press a specific key. Program cannot wait until user inputs. But when user press the key it should exit. Basically should work like a action listener using threads.

Comment: I have changed the sample to do what is described in your last comment. You should add a little housekeeping, like checking for the thread handles for NULL and releasing handles before exit.

Comment: One general note: I understand this is just an exercise, but in real programs threads are not supposed just to wait for each other. This in effect serializes processing and multithreading turns into an overhead without merit. You should put computationally intensive tasks on separate threads. Another use case for threads is taking long running procedures out of the UI thread.

Comment: But it doesn't exit the program whenever I press a key?

Comment: It does exit when you press a key. Just look at the code. After you press the key, it sets done = true, which is causing threads to return. Then it is waiting for threads to exit, then it terminates. When I run this code on my machine and press the key - it exits. Tell me what makes you think it doesn't.

Comment: I ran that code in my PC and when I press a key it prints on the screen.

Comment: What does it print on the screen?

Comment: What character do you press? The way it is done right now, you should press the <enter>. If you want to press any character to exit, you should replace getchar() with _getch();